# Why won't this gem be uninstalled

Tags: ruby, rubygems, bundler, gemfile

i installed a gem from this [repository](https://github.com/equivalent/copy_carrierwave_file) using this in my Gemfile :

```
gem 'copy_carrierwave_file', github: 'equivalent/copy_carrierwave_file'
```

when i'm trying to uninstall it using :

```
gem uninstall copy_carrierwave_file
```

nothing is shown like `copy_carrierwave is uninstalled successfuly from....`

then if i type :

```
bundle show copy_carrierwave_file
```

it still show me the location of this gem

How i can uninstall it ?

Comment: git, or path located, or development  gems are controlled by bunlder. just remove it from **Gemfile**

Comment: what do you means by they are controlled by bundler ?

Comment: I mean that such gems are to be chacked out by bundler, and then it creates a gem from the code.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since git, github, and path located, or development gems are controlled by bunlder, you have just to remove put to delete gem from **Gemfile**. And you even don't need to run `bundle install` again.

```
$ bundle show session

Could not find gem 'session'.
```

Answer (score 2):

Bundle Clean. Since the gems were installed using bundler, they have to be uninstalled using bundler too!

First, remove the line `gem 'copy_carrierwave_file', github: 'equivalent/copy_carrierwave_file'` from your `Gemfile`

Then, bundle clean with dry-run (just in case you see gems you don't want to remove):

```
bundle clean --force --dry-run
```

If you want to remove those gems, clean it:

```
bundle clean --force
```